# many =if 's to automatically fill in a column

Tags: function, if-statement, google-sheets, command

I am in Google Sheets, and I have a column with many choices from a drop down (retail stores, i.e.Home Depot, Walmart) and in another column I want a certain % for tax to get added to the price when the retail store is selected. So in row 2 if I select Walmart in that "retail" column, then in the "tax" column it will automatically insert 9%. When I select Menards from the retail list, in the tax column it would automatically insert 2%. I have 20+ retail stores that I want a certain % automatically inserted into another column. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you may need to add another table with list of all stores and taxes:

```
Walmart     9%
Menards     2%
Home Depot  3%
...         ..
```

and so on...

Lets call this new table "Store-Taxes". Then just use `vlookup formula`:

```
 A       B
Store   Tax
Name1   =ArrayFormula(Vlookup(offset(A2,,,counta(A2:A)), "Store-Taxes", 2, 0))
Name2   ...
Name3   ...
```

Replace "Store-Taxes" with table's actual reference, like `'Store-Taxes'!A:B`. Formula in cell `B2` will expand automatically. Look at [this example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DmSQxbrggcVl2j6mbcGtwFii9aa22j-_kju-j2oWdbE/edit?usp=sharing) to find out how this technique works.